# tabulating summation series with restrictions

Tags: list-manipulation, summation

[image]

Trying to solve this question for a good 5 hours but remained stuck. My intuition tells me I am missing something trivial that I've overlooked or forgotten.
I am restricted only to the function 'table', 'accumulate', 'tableform','total','range',.

Attached are my codes:

```
4 Table[ ((1 - Cos[n π])/(n π)^3 E^(-n π ξ) Sin[n π η]), {n, 1, 25}]

Length[sumterms3]

Total[sumterms3]

ξ = {0., 0.1, 0.2, 0., 0.1, 0.2};

η = {0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5}
```

Edit: I can confirm that if I were to sub xi=0 and eta =0.4 into

```
 Total[sumterms3]
```

0.239997 would be produced. However, I am looking for a better way to do so.

Answer (score 3):

```
TableForm[
 Flatten[Table[{η, ξ, 4 Total@Table[((1 - Cos[n π])/(n π)^3 E^(-n π ξ) Sin[n π η]), 
                                    {n, 1, 25}]},
              {η, {.4, .5}}, {ξ, {0, .1, .2}}], 1], 
 TableAlignments -> Center, 
 TableHeadings -> {{}, {"η", "ξ", "u(η,ξ)"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you can't use `Flatten[ ]` it's a little nastier:

```
ps = {{0.4, 0.}, {0.4, 0.1}, {0.4, 0.2}, {0.5, 0.}, {0.5, 0.1}, {0.5, 0.2}};
TableForm[
 Table[{p[[1]], p[[2]], 
        4 Total@Table[((1 - Cos[n π])/(n π)^3 E^(-n π p[[2]]) Sin[n π p[[1]]]), 
                      {n, 1, 25}]}, 
 {p, ps}], 
 TableAlignments -> Center, 
 TableHeadings -> {{}, {"η", "ξ", "u(η,ξ)"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
pl = {0., 0.1, 0.2, 0., 0.1, 0.2};
ql = {0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5};

fun = 4 Table[((1 - Cos[n Pi])/(n Pi)^3 E^(-n Pi p) Sin[n Pi q]), {n, 1, 25}];

res = MapThread[Total[fun /. {p -> #1, q -> #2}] &, {pl, ql}]
```

> {0.239997, 0.177074, 0.130061, 0.250007, 0.185091, 0.136277}

```
 Grid[Prepend[Transpose[{
    pl /. a_Real :> PaddedForm[a, {5, 1}],
    ql /. a_Real :> PaddedForm[a, {5, 1}],
    res /. a_Real :> PaddedForm[a, {8, 6}]}],
  {"p", "q", "u(p,q)"}],
 Alignment -> Right, Dividers -> All, Spacings -> {1, 2.5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
  u[\[Eta]_, \[Xi]_] := 
   Total[4 Table[((1 - Cos[n \[Pi]])/(n \[Pi])^3 E^(-n \[Pi] \[Xi]) Sin[
   n \[Pi] \[Eta]]), {n, 1, 25}]];

  list = Partition[
  Flatten[Table[{i, j, 
   u[i, j]}, {i, {0.4, 0.5}}, {j, {0, 0.1, 0.2}}]], 3];

  TableForm[list, 
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"\[Eta]", "\[Xi]", "u[\[Eta],\[Xi]]"}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just something different (but fundamentally `Tuples` is useful):

```
f[x_, y_] := 
 4 Composition[Dot @@ # &, 
    Transpose][{(1 - Cos[# Pi])/(# Pi)^3 Exp[-# Pi x], 
      Sin[# Pi y]} & /@ Range[25]]
```

Using `Tuples`:

```
TableForm[{#1, #2, f[#2, #1]} & @@@ 
  Tuples[{{0.4, 0.5}, {0,0.1, 0.2}}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"\[Eta]", "\[Xi]", "u(\[Eta],\[Xi])"}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did not use Greek characters, but I hope this answers your question:

```
sum[z_, v_] := 4 Sum[(1 - Cos[n π])/(n π)^3 Exp[-n π z] Sin[n π v], {n, 1, 25}]

Grid[Flatten[Table[{v, z, sum[z, v]}, {v, {0.4, 0.5}}, {z, {0, 0.1, 0.2}}], 1], 
    Frame -> All]
```

Comment: Dear God I forgot about the restrictions of the Homework problem !!